# Regular expression umlauts

Tags: regex, expression

I have 2 nodes with property.

Nodes

1. Name: 'Ümit'
2. Name: 'Umit'

How can I get this 2 nodes with following statement:

```
match n where n.Profilname =~ 'Umit' return n
```

Answer (score 1):

As Lucas already noted in a comment, you could do that with `[UÜ]mit`, however, that will fail if you got »Ümit« instead of »Ümit«, i.e. a decomposed Ü (U, followed by U+0308) instead of the precomposed one. To solve that you could either normalize your string beforehand and then either use `[UÜ]mit` (precomposed) or `(U|Ü)mit` (decomposed), depending on the normalization form, or include the possibility in your regex: `(U|Ü|Ü)mit`.